# How to make an element the full height of a page?

Tags: html

Is there  a way that I could set  a DIV element to take up all the height on the page. Something like:

```
div.left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I've Google'd it a few times but they all seem like really really complicated work arounds for what is probably a really really simple problem with a simple solution.

Comment: Working fine: [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/n6Lh3/)

Comment: Thanks bro. I messed up and didn't add any content to the div... must be getting late!

Thanks once again!

Josh

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the `div` is a direct child of `body`, this works:

```
body, html {height: 100%; }
div { height: 100%; }
```

Otherwise, you have to keep adding `height: 100%` to each of it's parents, grandparents,... untill you've reached a direct child of `body`.

It's simple. For a percentage height to work, the parent must have a specified height(px, %... whichever). If it does not, then it's as if you've set `height: auto`;

Another way to do it is as you have in your answer: it's to give it an absolute position value, relative to the element that defines the page's height.

Answer (score 11):

This is the simplest way to make a div take up the full height of a page.

```
height: 100vh;
```

`vh` is **Viewport Height**, and `1vh` is equal to 1% of the height of the viewport. See [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/) for more details on this and other units of measurement in CSS.

Comment: Please, can you be elaborate on the stated answer..? Like I will like to know why 100vh worked but 100% didn't. Thanks.

Comment: @ThunderBird Super late but I just found out the reason this works is because by default the body and html tags don't have a size till content is inside, so just calling 100vh tells the div to follow the viewport size instead of checking the size of the parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` so that the div has a context for height! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to set the `html` and `body` to 100%:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.left {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ultranaut/yMPkv/).

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using `CSS` flexbox.
Go through the w3schools documentation of flexbox [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and another helpful link css-tricks [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

In this scenario.

put display: flex; in the parent div container

```
div.container{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

then in the child div put display: 1;

```
div.left{
  height: 100%;
  display: 1;
}
```

note that if the height of the parent div container is set dynamically, the child div will always have the same height as the parent.

Comment: "display" does not take a numeric value:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#formal_syntax
Maybe your intention was setting "flex-grow: 1"?